# Reshape a six-dimensional array into a 2d dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a six-dimensional numeric array A, and I want to reshape it into a two-dimensional array. The rows of the resulting matrix should be multi-indexed by the first three dimensions of A, and the columns should be multi-indexed by the last three dimensions of A. What is the best way to achieve this using pandas or numpy?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a handy function to do just this.

```
def make2d(a):
    shape = a.shape
    n = len(shape)
    col_lvls = n // 2
    idx_lvls = n - col_lvls

    midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [range(i) for i in shape[:idx_lvls]],
        names=['d-{}'.format(d) for d in range(1, idx_lvls + 1)])
    mcol = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [range(i) for i in shape[idx_lvls:]],
        names=['d-{}'.format(d) for d in range(idx_lvls + 1, idx_lvls + col_lvls + 1)])

    return pd.DataFrame(
        a.reshape(np.array(shape[:3]).prod(), -1),
        midx, mcol
    )
```

---

***demonstration***

```
a = np.arange(216).reshape(2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3)

make2d(a)
```

[image]